# Regex help (php)

Tags: php, regex

I am in need of help about regular expressions (PHP). So I have an textarea box where user can input orders.

For example:

```
see north,
see south,
sell 7 wood,
see west
```

I need a regular expression that matches the following rules:

- Each order is separated by comma, except the last one
- The order is either (see north, see south, see west, see east) or (buy/sell % wood). % - represent number (maximum is 999 and minimum is 1 with no head zeroes)

So far I have made this regular expression:

```
preg_match("/(((see) (north|south|west|east))|((sell|buy) ([1-9][0-9]{0,2}) (wood)))/");
```

But the problem is, the following input also is valid, which should be not:
sell 75 wood see north (it should be either **sell 75 wood** OR **see north**)

NB! Right now I don't have comma validation in my regular expression, because I use PHP function explode to split with commas and then pass resulting array items to regex. But it doesn't seem to work with the following input:

```
see north,
see south        *(no comma between two orders)*
sell 7 wood,
see west
```

So, I need one of the following solutions:

- Regular expression has comma validation (see rules)
- I explode the input string with the PHP explode function and restrict that the following input is not valid: sell 75 wood see north

Thanks.

Comment: Four your #2 - use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), like `^(?:see (?:north|south|west|east)|(?:sell|buy) [1-9][0-9]{0,2} wood)$`

Comment: You did not anchor your pattern to the beginning and end of the test string - therefor `see south sell 7 wood` gives a positive result, because `see south` alone already satisfies the first part of your |-joined pattern.

Comment: Thank you, it seemed to work. Though, I need to write some unit-tests to make sure it does what it is supposed to do. And of course, I will take a deeper look into regular expressions. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Approach 2: [`^(see +(?:north|south|west|east)|(?:sell|buy) +(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3}) wood)$`](https://regex101.com/r/uV7hI8/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a Regex for this. This is a job for a (basic) parser.

Do whatever you need to get one command at a time. This could be `explode`, for instance. Use `trim` if necessary to remove whitespace from the start and end.

Then, `$parts = explode(" ",$command);`

You can now `switch($parts[0])` to determine what to do based on the first keyword.

```
case "see":
    if( !in_array($parts[1], ["north","south","east","west"])) {
        throw new OutOfBoundsException("Invalid direction");
    }
    // do something here
    break;
```

Notice how validation is super easy and it's possible to provide *specific* error messages so that the user knows what they did wrong.

```
case "sell":
    $q = intval($parts[1]);
    if( $q < 1 || $q > 999) {
        throw new OutOfBoundsException("Invalid amount of things to sell");
    }
    $what = $parts[2];
    if( !in_array($what, ["wood"])) {
        throw new OutOfBoundsException("Invalid thing to sell");
    }
    // do something
    break;

default:
    throw new OutOfBoundsException("Invalid command");
```

This whole process is all about taking a big problem and breaking it down. It's also very, very easy to change how it works, what commands and parameters are allowed, etc. Changing a regex would be much harder.

Comment: I also like this approach as well. The thing is, sometimes I get too overwhelmed by the options, how to solve specific problem and I am not sure what's the best way.